# Typescript sequelize associations double column output

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I'm building some tables models using sequelize with typescript.

Here's one of my models:

```
'use strict';
import { Model, InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes, CreationOptional } from 'sequelize';

module.exports = (sequelize: any, DataTypes: any) => {
  class Package extends Model<InferAttributes<Package>, InferCreationAttributes<Package>> {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    declare id: CreationOptional<number>;
    declare packageName: string;
    declare price: number;
    declare duration: Date;

    static associate(models: any) {
      Package.hasMany(models.Payment);
    }
  }

  Package.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      field: 'package_id'
    },
    packageName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'package_name'
    },
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    duration: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Package',
  });

  return Package;
};
```

i want to create a one to many relation with payments table (each payment should have a package id)
sequelize says that you should define the association in two ways like this

```
static associate(models: any) {
      Payment.belongsTo(models.Package,({foreignKey: 'package_id'}));
    }
```

But I end up with two columns referring to the `package_id` in payments table in return, if I dropped one of the definitions it works fine but I don't know if it's going to set me back in the future, do you guys have an idea why it's acting like this?

Should end up with one column.

Answer (score 0):

actually found the solution, I needed to specify the same foreign key used in the payment model in the package model.